# PHP and special characters

Tags: php, character

I need help with transmitting foreign characters via forms.  Characters like ü and é.  I have been reading the documentation on mb_language and mb_convert_encoding, and can get it to work for Japanese characters, but not for European characters.  There seems to be no mb_language('de') for German as there is mb_language('ja') for Japansese.

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
$subjectAutoresponder = 'Vielen Dank für Ihre Kontaktaufnahme';
$subjectAutoresponder = mb_convert_encoding($subjectAutoresponder, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
$subjectAutoresponder = mb_encode_mimeheader($subjectAutoresponder);
```

Can someone help me?  In the header, it eliminates the ü rather than converting it.  Also, what do I need to do to get a form to submit foreign characters.  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set your page's encoding to UTF-8 and then avoid this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell PHP to use a certain internal encoding when it stores strings in memory.

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output("UTF-8");
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
```

Put this code at the start of your PHP code (I'm hoping you have some sort of common header file that every other page includes).

Comment: Ganz genau. Vielen dank :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using ISO-8859-1. Try encoding everything with UTF-8. It handles quite every character i can think of. You do not need to encode anything manually.

Comment: Here is what I have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: The meta-tag does not make your page UTF-8. You need to save your files in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @user403888 That's not how you do it, see my answer below.

Comment: @spartan018: You _should_ do it like that. You do not need any additional code when using the right encoding.

Comment: @elusive I still prefer to be rather explicit about setting that stuff. And unless he's using a really borked editor, it should be encoding his files as UTF-8 already, since he's hardcoding the ü into the file.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried putting that in my form, and I still get the wrong characters as output in the emails my form sends.  Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, email is a bit different. See http://bitprison.net/php_mail_utf-8_subject_and_message